# Count lexemes - string out of bounds exception

Tags: java

I have a small program that is suppose to count lexemes. What I get is an erorr. I am fairly new to Java. Here is the error:

```
c:\programming>java LexemesTokenizer
input string: a = ++b; c = d - /* -e */ --f;
Input string= a
Delimeter=  .
Total number of delimeters= 2 Exception in thread "main" java.lang.StringIndexOu
tOfBoundsException: String index out of range: 2
    at java.lang.String.charAt(Unknown Source)
    at LexemesTokenizer.main(LexemesTokenizer.java:41)
```

Here is the code

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class LexemesTokenizer {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);

        System.out.print("input string: ");
        String s = scanner.next();

        char delimiter = ' ';

        // calculate number of delimiter characters
        int cntDelimeters = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < s.length(); i++) {
            if (s.charAt(i) != delimiter) {
                cntDelimeters++;
            }
        }

        System.out.println("Input string= " + s);
        System.out.printf("Delimeter= %c.", delimiter);
        System.out.printf("\nTotal number of delimeters= %d ", cntDelimeters);
        String[] lexemes = new String[cntDelimeters + 1];

        // parse cntDelimeters+1 lexemes and store in an array
        int right = 0;
        int left = 0;

        for (int i = 0; i < cntDelimeters; i++) {
            while (s.charAt(right) != delimiter) {
                right++;
            }

            lexemes[i] = s.substring(left, right);
            right++;
            left = right;
        }

        lexemes[cntDelimeters] = s.substring(right, s.length());

        // print results for testing
        for (int i = 0; i < lexemes.length; i++) {
            System.out.printf("\n%d : %s", i, lexemes[i]);
        }
    }
}
```

line 41 is:while (s.charAt(right) != delimiter) {

Some reason string s is only an a

any help is much appreciated.

Comment: Would you point out line 41 for us please so we don't have to count?

Comment: In the part where you say you "//calculate number of delimiter characters", you appear to be counting the number of characters which in fact are NOT delimiters. Look at the comparison you use before incrementing the "cntDelimiters" variable. Dunno if that has anything to do with your error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, your string (`s`) doesn't contain a space (the value you assigned to `delimiter`) and then you do this:

```
while (s.charAt(right) != delimiter) {
    right++;
}
```

Thus flying right off the end of your string.

```
while (s.charAt(right) != delimiter && s.length > right)
```

Will take care of that.

**Edit:** To help with the input string

You're calling

```
String s = scanner.next();
```

`Scanner` is an input parser. This is going to return the first word of your input ("a") because the default delimiter is whitespace.

If you want the entire line of input you use:

```
 String s = scanner.nextLine();
```

Comment: i am having the same problem. input string is only one character for some reason

Comment: i added line 41 so you can see where the error is coming from

Comment: @Brian - i tried nextline and it still just reads in "a" for some reason.

Comment: nevermind i got it working.. sorry - its still out of range though - i tried your solution..